# Highlight tab-separated values based on a couple of rules

Tags: shell, terminal, colorize, text-coloring, ansi-colors

I have some tab-separated file for which I want to conditionally highlight certain columns or certain values.

Example of source file:

```
wn       name          Building Name       8       Desc       char       -> bl
wo       bl_id!*       Building Code       8                  char
```

I want to:

- put in yellow the contents of the 2nd column when the name is suffixed by "!"
- put in cyan the contents of the 2nd column and in green the contents of the 7th column when there is such a 7th column
- put the little "*" sign in red, in the 2nd column

and a couple of other such rules.

Currently I do that in this way:

```
cat file.tsv
    | sed -r 's/^([^\t]*)\t([^\t]*)!/\1\t\x1b[33m\2!\x1b[0m/' \
    | sed -r 's/^^([^\t]*)\t([^\t]*)\t(.*)\t-> ([^\t]+)/\1\t\x1b[36m\2\x1b[0m\t\3\t-> \x1b[32m\4\x1b[0m/' \
    | sed -r 's/\*/\x1b[31;1m&\x1b[0m/'
```

But it's quite complex to read and update.

Is there a better way?  I'm quite sure of, but which one?

Are things like GRC or Supercat a way to go?  Though, I have to admit that I have a quite important constraint: I'd like the solution to work out-of-the-box in Cygwin.  Don't want to have to compile myself tools in there -- for portability reasons of my code.

Can you give hints on how to improve the code to get such a "highlight" functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with GNU awk, like this (col.awk):

```
function colText ( text, col) { 
    return sprintf("\033[%sm%s\033[39;0m", col, text); 
}

function yellow( text ){ return colText( text, "33;1" ); }
function cyan  ( text ){ return colText( text, "36;1" ); }
function green ( text ){ return colText( text, "32;1" ); }
function red   ( text ){ return colText( text, "31;1" ); } 

BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t";}

# red * in $2
$2 ~ /\*/ {gsub(/\*/, red("*"), $2); }

# cyan if col 7 present
NF == 7 {print $1, cyan($2), $3, $4, $5, $6, green( $7 ) ;
         next;}

# yellow col2 if there is a !  
$2 ~ /!/ {print $1, yellow($2), $3, $4, $5, $6, $7 }
```

Use it like this `gawk -f col.awk file.tsv`

Comment: Note that this is a bit more scary to adapt, in the sense that sed never suppressed lines nor duplicated them. With an awk script, that kind of things can happen, if we're not sufficiently cautious...

Answer (score 1):

You could make the script more readable by using shell variables (and [`tput`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html) for portability across terminal types):

```
BOLD_RED=$(tput setaf 1; tput bold)
GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
YELLOW=$(tput setaf 3)
CYAN=$(tput setaf 6)
COLOR_OFF=$(tput sgr0)

cat file.tsv
    | sed -r 's/^([^\t]*)\t([^\t]*)!/\1\t'"$YELLOW"'\2!'"$COLOR_OFF"'/' \
    | sed -r 's/^([^\t]*)\t([^\t]*)\t(.*)\t-> ([^\t]+)/\1\t'"$CYAN"'\2'"$COLOR_OFF"'\t\3\t-> '"$GREEN"'\4'"$COLOR_OFF"'/' \
    | sed -r 's/\*/'"$BOLD_RED"'&'"$COLOR_OFF"'/'
```

Likewise, you could make a variable for the regular expression chunk which is everything but tabs, e.g.,

```
NO_TABS='([^\t]*)'
```

By the way, one of the `sed` expressions repeated `^` (a typo).

Comment: Your proposition is already an improvement of my code (and thanks for the typo), but I'm accepteing Lars' answer which allows more easily to define highlighting rules than in sed. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: In which shell (available from Cygwin?) could I check for portability issues?  IOW, in which ones do codes such as `\e[31m` not work?

Comment: Not all terminals *support* ANSI colors.  Deferring that to the terminal database lets users suppress colors if they choose.

Comment: Aahh, it's a question of terminal, not shell... This is sometimes blurry for me...